# regex for replacement of value text from child tags using id of parent tag

Tags: python, regex

```
<Galactus id="ironman">
    <GalactusId>METALIC</GalactusId>
    <GalactusName>COMMUNICATOR</GalactusName>
</Galactus>

<Galactus id="HULK">
    <GalactusId>BULKY</GalactusId>
    <GalactusName>CRUSHER</GalactusName>
</Galactus>
```

I want to replace GalactusId value to "Galactus id" i.e HULK or ironman + First 3character from existing GalactusId
and same for GalactusName. so the out sould look like.

```
<Galactus id="ironman">
    <GalactusId>ironman_MET</GalactusId>
    <GalactusName>ironman_COM</GalactusName>
</Galactus>

<Galactus id="HULK">
    <GalactusId>HULK_BUL</GalactusId>
    <GalactusName>HULK_CRU</GalactusName>
</Galactus>
```

All child tags should change accordingly, not just these two.

Comment: Is this a snippet of a valid xml?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1028589) practise to parse XML or HTML with regex. You should use XML Parser. For Python, [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is probably most popular.

```
import lxml.etree
xml = lxml.etree.fromstring('''
<xml>
    <Galactus id="ironman">
        <GalactusId>METALIC</GalactusId>
        <GalactusName>COMMUNICATOR</GalactusName>
    </Galactus>

    <Galactus id="HULK">
        <GalactusId>BULKY</GalactusId>
        <GalactusName>CRUSHER</GalactusName>
    </Galactus>
</xml>''')

for galactus in xml.iterfind('.//Galactus'):
    for child in galactus.getchildren():
        child.text = galactus.attrib['id'] + '_' + child.text[:3]

print(lxml.etree.tostring(xml).decode())
```